# Inferring String value type in Groovy

Tags: java, date, reflection, groovy, introspection

I have a situation where I will be given a String and I need to determine what `Class<?>` best suits its value given the following constraints:

- If the String is (ignoring case) equal to `"true"` or `"false"`, it's a `Boolean`
- Else, if the String is an integral number with no decimal point, it's an `Integer`
- Else, if the String is a number, it's a `Double`
- Else, if the String matches the date time format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss`, then its a Java `Date`
- Else it's just a `String` afterall

My best attempt is nasty and involves a lot of nested `try/catch` blocks:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
Class<?> determineValueType(String value) {
    Class<?> clazz
    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase('true') || value.equalsIgnoreCase('false')) {
        clazz = Boolean
    } else {
        try {
            Integer.parse(value)
            clazz = Integer
        } catch(Exception ex1) {
            try {
                Double.parse(value)
                clazz = Double
            } catch(Exception ex2) {
                try {
                    Date.parse('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss', value)
                    clazz = Date
                } catch(Exception ex3) {
                    clazz = String
                }
            }
        }
    }

    clazz
}
```

Are there any *Groovier* ways of accomplishing this, perhaps something endemic to some obscure Groovy reflection API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods which can help you in Groovy's extended [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) class (actually on `CharSequence`):

- [`isInteger`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#isInteger())
- [`isDouble`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#isDouble())

But for other cases, AFAIK, you are on your own to implement the parsing. You could try working with a map and some closures, to reduce some boilerplate:

```
Class parse(val) {
    def convert = [
        (Integer) : { it.toInteger() },
        (Double)  : { it.toDouble() },
        (Date)    : { Date.parse('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss', it) },
        (Boolean) : { Boolean.parseBoolean it },
        (String)  : { it }
    ]

    convert.findResult { key, value ->
        try {
            if (value(val)) return key
        } catch (e) {}
    }
}

assert parse('9.1') == Double
assert parse('9') == Integer
assert parse('1985-10-26 01:22:00.000') == Date // great scott!
assert parse('chicken') == String
assert parse('True') == Boolean
```

Note that if `(Double)` precedes `(Integer)` the tests won't work, since `9` is both a double and a integer.

Answer (score 3):

Groovy has a few features that would allow you to make this logic groovier.

1. The powerful [switch](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html) statement, which supports regexes and closures.
2. The [`isInteger`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#isInteger()) and `isDouble` built-in CharSequence methods from the Groovy JDK. Sadly, there's not a strict `isBoolean` so we'll need to implement that ourselves.
3. The [safe navigation operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator) to avoid NPEs.

Combining these features...

```
Class<?> determineValueType(String value) {
    switch (value) {
        case { ['true', 'false'].contains(value?.toLowerCase()) }: 
            return Boolean
        case { value?.isInteger() }: 
            return Integer
        case { value?.isDouble() }: 
            return Double
        case ~/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}$/: 
            return Date
        default: 
            return String
    }
}

assert determineValueType('true') == Boolean
assert determineValueType('false') == Boolean
assert determineValueType('2039230') == Integer
assert determineValueType('203923.0') == Double
assert determineValueType('2016-07-26 12:00:00.000') == Date
assert determineValueType('foo') == String
```

I used a regex instead of SimpleDateFormat to avoid having to catch an Exception. It probably has slightly difference semantics, but you could alternatively create a helper method that returns false if there's an Exception thrown by `Date.parse`.